# draw rectangles and annotate webpage

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best utility/API to use in order to draw rectangles and annotate a webpage within the browser?

I need the user to be able to draw a box over the existing HTML content and type a message into an annotation for the box.

Similar functionality can be found [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html) - OpenLayers allows you to draw shapes on the map.

**EDIT:**

I need the solution to be cross-browser, and as lightweight as possible. PrototypeJS is already embedded in this application, if that can be leveraged then that is a bonus.

Comment: The minimum solution I'm looking for makes it clear how to enable the user to create a box over an existing html document.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what kind of project you are working on, but choose one environment (which supports drawing rectangles over other content) and do everything within that environment. You could, for example, use HTML5 canvas. (If you search through OpenLayers.js a bit, you'll see they did the same)

This is a great resource to get started: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/