# Get input values and insert into function with two parameters to make rectangle?

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, parameters

I am new beginner in javascript and I am not sure how to take the gathered input values (width and height), which then need to create a method called updateForm which takes a width and height parameter. The body of the function can set the width and height fields on the input form, and call a method to draw that rectangle on the canvas.

JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rtomino/hbgmd4sg/2/

```
<form id="areaform">
   <label for="wid">Width:</label>
   <input id="wid" type="number">
   <label for="hgt">Height:</label>
   <input id="hgt" type="number">

  <button onclick="draw()" type="button">Draw Rectangle</button>
</form>

<br>

<div id="drawRectangle">
<canvas id="rectCanvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
</div>
```

JS

```
var canvas, 
    context, 
    widthValue = document.getElementById('wid'),
    heightValue = document.getElementById('hgt');

canvas = document.getElementById("rectCanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function updateForm(width, height) {
   'use strict';

 }


function draw() {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   context.rect(0, 0, width, height);
   context.fillStyle = "#EA7B00";
   context.fill();
}
```

Comment: functions have parameters, if you call them you pass arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `updateForm` function in this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/mMerZE?editors=1010)**, as well as the snippet below.

The canvas width/height is set to 100% to give you room to make your rectangles very big, but you can set the canvas dimension whatever you'd like in the JavaScript.

```js
function updateForm(width, height) {
  "use strict";
  //Position parameters used for drawing the rectangle
  var x = 50;
  var y = 50;
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //Create a canvas element
  //Set canvas width/height
  canvas.style.width = "100%";
  canvas.style.height = "100%";
  // Set canvas drawing area width/height
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  //Position canvas
  canvas.style.position = "absolute";
  canvas.style.left = 0;
  canvas.style.top = 0;
  canvas.style.zIndex = 100000;
  canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none"; //Make sure you can click 'through' the canvas
  document.body.appendChild(canvas); //Append canvas to body element
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //Draw rectangle
  context.rect(x, y, width, height);
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.fill();
}

function draw() {
  var width = document.getElementById("wid").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
  updateForm(width, height);
}
```

```html
<form id="areaform">
  <label for="wid">Width:</label>
  <input id="wid" type="number">
  <label for="hgt">Height:</label>
  <input id="hgt" type="number">

  <button onclick="draw()" type="button">Draw Rectangle</button>
</form>
```

This solution is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840907/draw-rectangle-over-html-with-javascript).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! But unfortunately it's not using a function called updateForm. Basically I need to create a method called updateForm which takes a width and height parameter. The body of the function can set the width and height fields on the input form, and call a method to draw that rectangle on the canvas. I'm just stuck on how to use the parameters for it.

Comment: @logan26 I've updated the answer to include the `updateForm` function - you only really need one function here, but you can use 2 if you'd like - sometimes that is good for readability.

Comment: Got it to work! I guess it's just confusing to me because I'm used to tutorials using updateForm(20,20) with numbers inside for arguments when you call it. But it'll be inserted with inputs by the user, so that's why I was confused. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help :)